# HP Proliant DL160 G6 - Hardware RAID card to get?

Tags: raid, hardware, hp-proliant

I have bought a DL160 G6 server (Product number: 490427R-001 ) and it does not come with a hardware RAID card. I am trying to set up a VMWare Esxi server and as such I would need a hardware RAID card. I am just wondering if there is any card that would fit into the chassis? Would a P200i fits? How about a P400? Also, would there be any non-HP RAID card that will do the magic too? I have 4 SATA 160GB hard drives already plugged in.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic here.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should purchase one of the [supported controllers for this server](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13247_na/13247_na.html#Storage). That really only includes the Smart Array P212, P410 and P812 controllers. If you're planning to use this with VMWare, you'll want to purchase the card with a battery-backed or flash-backed cache. I typically recommend the Smart Array P410, as it's readily available, will fit in either slot on the server and won't require any additional parts.

Answer (score 0):

The P410 card is supported by both your DL160 G6 and all recent versions of ESXi, I'd recommend the P410/512 version which is part number 578230-B21.

Comment: Thanks, do I need a raiser card for DL160?

Comment: If you only have the 2-disk version (P/N: 518593-B21) then you'll need the 4-disk version (P/N: 512181-B21) instead.